# NSImageView won't scale image down if frame style is NSImageFrameNone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimageview

I need to display `NSImageView` on resizable `NSWindow`. The image displayed in the view should scale down if it's too big to fit image view in the widnow and it should also change its size when resizing the window. I am able to achieve correct behavior using Auto-Layout, and setting `imageScaling` property of `NSImageView` to `NSImageScaleProportionallyDown`. Unfortunately it's not working when my image view's `imageFrameStyle` property is set to `NSImageFrameNone` (it works for any other option like `NSImageFramePhoto` or `NSImageFrameGrayBezel`). I don't want any frame to be displayed, like with `NSImageFrameNone`, but disabling the frame breaks autoresizing - it looks like with frame set to `NSImageFrameNone` image is not scaled down and `NSImageView` is scaled up to match displayed image size. Anyone have solution for that issue?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It occurs that it's easier than I thought. The problem was with Auto-Layout, not with NSImageView scaling logic. Using InterfaceBuilder with my image view selected I had to change "Content Compression Resistance Priority" to lower value (it's located on Size Inspector tab in Xcode5). That solved my problem and the image is now scaled properly when resizing window.

Comment: Could you please help me out on one issue. Actually I have a view with certain dimensions 817x460, I have objects in that view like NSButton,NSImageView etc. But when I maximise the view, the objects are not getting stretched, i.e. the size is constant even upon using auto-layout and your solution. Could you please tell me how to enlarge the views and objects to make it compatible with window size. Please help me, thanks :)